# Screen flickering and flashing continually when i navigate from one screen to another

Tags: flutter, google-maps

Here is the video showing the problem:

https://streamable.com/ge4z0b

I have a Google Map screen, which shows a dialog on initialization and when you click the OK button of the dialog, you are redirected to the next screen, which has AR and camera implemented.

This happens only when i navigate from the Map Screen to AR screen. When i put AR screen as first screen, it doesnt flicker and works as it supposed to work.

Both screens are stateful and both are wrapped into Scaffolds.

Any idea why this happens?

I tried removing Scaffolds and a lot of suggestions from the community but nothing seems to work.

You can view the code here : https://codeshare.io/OdREVA

Comment: can you please share your code? so that we can understand and give you a better solution.

Comment: @faysalneowaz https://codeshare.io/OdREVA Here you have the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Screen flickering and flashing during navigation can be caused by a number of factors, including:

Performance issues: The cause of the screen flickering could be due to performance issues with the device or the app. If the app is not optimized or if the device is slow, it may cause the screen to flicker.

Stateful widgets: If you are using stateful widgets in your app, it may cause the screen to flicker if the state changes during navigation. Consider using stateless widgets instead.

Animations: If you are using animations in your app, it may cause the screen to flicker if the animation is not optimized or if it is too complex. Consider simplifying the animation or optimizing it for performance.

Flutter framework bugs: In some cases, the screen flickering issue could be caused by bugs in the Flutter framework itself. Consider filing a bug report with the Flutter team if you believe this to be the case.

Third-party plugins: If you are using third-party plugins in your app, it may cause the screen to flicker if the plugin is not optimized or if it is causing conflicts with other parts of the app. Consider disabling or removing the plugin to see if it resolves the issue.

It is difficult to determine the exact cause of the screen flickering without more information, such as the code and any related logs. Consider providing more information or filing a bug report with the Flutter team for a more accurate diagnosis

Comment: https://codeshare.io/OdREVA You can find my code here, hopefully, this can help you out. Thanks!